# gitlab ci false passed

Tags: shell, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am using gitlab CI to test my application, and I am using gradle to run the tests.

However, even when my test fail, the job yields passed wrongly, as you can see of part of console output below.

```
BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2 mins 29.452 secs

Build succeeded
```

Answer (score 3):

GitLab CI uses the process exit code to determine if a job passes or fails. If your tests print "BUILD FAILED" but exits with an exit code of zero then GitLab thinks your tests passed.

You need to configure your tests to return a non-zero exit code on failure.